# Alter table with adding Indexes to table [MariaDB]

Tags: mariadb

I have a table where I'm trying to add indexes to it, but for some reason it writes out an error.
I use `MySQL Workbench 8.0.17`, and the database is `10.1.25-MariaDB`.

The error I get when I use my workbench to add indexes is the following:

[image]

It's the first time I try this, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here?

Extra information about my tables: one of my tables is called `TestResults` and it has the following columns:

[image]

I then made a table that links `TestResults` and another table called `testcaserequirement` together, and this table is called `testresultsrequirementlink` which has the id's of both tables in each column.

[image]

Here I want to make `requimrentId` and `testresultId` a  **index** and also make a **foreign key** between `testresultsrequirementlink.testresultId` and `testresults.id` and  also between `testresultsrequirementlink.requirementId` and `testcaserequirement.id`.

**EDIT**

I've looked at MariaDB syntax, and found two examples, but my database 'Lost connection' during the sql query run?`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please search Manual Reference for MariaDB and point us to any place where it tells about `VISIBLE` related to an index..

Comment: @Akina I've looked at the MariaDB manual and found that I shouldn't write VISIBLE after the index because it's visiable by default, but now my database loses connection (error)? Do  you know why?

Comment: This might help [mysql-connectivity-error](https://samirbehara.com/2019/09/10/mysql-connectivity/)

Comment: Thanks  for the help everyone, I managed to find the solution to all my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found my problem, the syntax for MariaDB was different and I couldn't find the right way to write it. But with help from the comments, I found somthing that worked.

```sql
#Create indexes
ALTER TABLE `testresultrequirementlink` 
ADD INDEX `navn` (`testresultId` );

#Create foreign keys
ALTER TABLE testresults ADD CONSTRAINT fk_testresultId FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES testresultrequirementlink(testresultId);
```

My problem creating the foreign keys, was because one of my mates had made a duplicate of a signel test, which resulted in duplicated id's...

Thanks for the help